# Replace quantity field with a form if product is out of stock in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, contact-form-7

In woocommerce, using [contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) plugin, I'm trying to replace the product quantity field, in the product summary, with a form, when a product is out of stock.

It works fine on variable products but on simple products it still shows the form and the quantity box.

It feels like I'm overlooking something very basic.

I've replaced the different `echo` with "simple" and "variable" to find out which form is shown, **but on simple products it still shows the 'variable' form**.

Here is my code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'add_form' );
function add_form() {
    global $product;

    if( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ){
        // a simple product
        if(!$product->is_in_stock( )) {
            echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="304" title="Contact stock"]');
            //echo "simple";
        }
    } elseif( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ){
        // a variable product
        $count_in_stock == 0;
        $variation_ids = $product->get_children(); // Get product variation IDs

        foreach( $variation_ids as $variation_id ){
            $variation = wc_get_product($variation_id);
            if( $variation->is_in_stock() )
                $count_in_stock++;
        }   
    }

    if( $count_in_stock == 0 ) {
        echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="304" title="Contact stock"]');
        //echo "variable";
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code, that will replace quantity field **and add to cart button** with a form when the product is "out of stock" *(for all product types, including variable products)*.

You say *"on simple products it still shows the 'variable' form"*: It's because you are using the same shortcode on both simple and variable products. **So you will need to add the correct different shortcode for simple products.**

The code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'action_single_product_summary_callback', 4 );
function action_single_product_summary_callback() {
    global $product;

    // Variable products
    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ){
        $count_in_stock = 0;

        foreach ( $product->get_visible_children() as $variation_id ) {
            $variation = wc_get_product($variation_id);

            if( $variation->is_in_stock() ) {
                $count_in_stock++;
            }
        }
        if ( $count_in_stock === 0 ) {
            // Remove quantity field and add to cart button
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
            // Display the contact form
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'display_variable_product_out_of_stock_form', 20 );
        }
    }
    // Other products (Simple … )
    else {
        if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() ) {
            // Remove quantity field and add to cart button
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
            // Display the contact form
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'display_simple_product_out_of_stock_form', 30 );
        }
    }
}

// Form for variable products
function display_variable_product_out_of_stock_form() {
    echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="304" title="Contact stock"]');
}

// Form for Simple products
function display_simple_product_out_of_stock_form() {
    echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="304" title="Contact stock"]'); // <== NOT the correct shortcode
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear response. It worked perfectly and I learned from your explanation.